# Jquery ajax postback not hitting server method?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

This is some of the code on the aspx page with the ajax post:

```
<div>
    Make Comment: <br />
    <textarea rows="7" cols="20" id="comment_content"></textarea><br />
    <input type="button" id="Make_Comment" value="Make Comment" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Make_Comment").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Conversation.aspx/AddComment",
                data: '{ comment: This is a test comment via ajax postback }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Got Back to code");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the method I am trying to hit on the server side:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void AddComment(string data)
    {

    }
```

I have placed a breakpoint by the server side method but its not hitting it, what could be the issue?

Comment: I'm not a asp.net developer, but your resource path is ok? Using `Conversation.aspx/AddComment` in your browser are you getting something? This `WebMethod` responses to GET and POST by default? Why are you sending a String in data instead of using an object?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things :

your `data`  ina `ajax` call

```
  data: '{ comment: This is a test comment via ajax postback }'
```

should be

```
 data: "{'comment':'This is a test comment via ajax postback'}",
```

And  your `WebMethod` :

```
 AddComment(string data)
```

Should be

```
 AddComment(string comment)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Make_Comment").click(function () {
        var comment = $("#comment_content").val();
        var Params = { comment : comment };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Conversation.aspx/AddComment",
            data: Params,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("Got Back to code");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In your controller set the httppost.

```
[WebMethod]
[HttpPost]
public static void AddComment(string comment)
{

}
```